# 'print render($content['links']);'

Tags: 7, theming

Which links is Drupal referring to in 'print render($content['links']? 'Links' is kind of general to me so I am wondering which links this php snippet is referring to.

I've looked at Drupal's theming references and saw only a list of variables for theming.

Answer (score 2):

The links it is referring to are the comment links, statistics links and translation links of a node.

So in a situation where you want just the comment links, it would be

```
print render($content['links']['comment']);
```

For more information, see this page.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_pre_render_links/7

Comment: Worth to remember that contributed modules can provide their own links, so just rendering all elements that are in `$content['links']` now and not rendering `$content['links']` themselves is a mistake if you are creating custom theme.